# How to call rails create method for json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

What is the URL of `JSON` response if someone send the data on `JSON` using `POST` method. How can I store that data in my blog controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create a proper routes and send that with the dataType 'Json' in ajax method. For example :-

```
  function save_data(url, result){
      $.ajax(url, {
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          store_data: result,
        },
        success: function() {

       }
     });
    }
```

In this method you can pass url and data which you want to send in the method you are calling by url you can fetch that data in your controller by `params[:store_data]` .